# Efficient and clean awk variable export

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sh

Having this variable/String computed:

```
RES={"message":"Got an invalid (or empty) URL"}404
```

I separate the two parts (on both sides of the "}") doing so:

```
CODE=`echo $RES | awk 'BEGIN {FS="}"}{print $2}'`
RES=`echo $RES | awk 'BEGIN {FS="}"}{print $1"}"}'`
```

Which brings me successfully:

```
CODE=404
RES={"message":"Got an invalid (or empty) URL"}
```

Can you think of a clean and more efficient way to do this?

For example, I would like to do something like this:

```
echo $RES | awk 'BEGIN {FS="}"} { CODE=$2; RES=$1;}'
```

I know it is far fetched but you can see what I mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the shell's string manipulation and save millions of CPU cycles for forking and executing awk:

```
$ RES='{"message":"Got an invalid (or empty) URL"}404'
$ echo ${RES%\}*}\}
{"message":"Got an invalid (or empty) URL"}
$ echo ${RES##*\}}
404
```

See your sh(1) or bash(1) manual section "Parameter Expansion" for details.

Comment: Perfect solution, I'm going through man right now to understand it.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Bity Glad it works for you. The next step on Stackoverflow would be to *accept* an answer by clicking the check symbol to the left under the down arrow. Accepting answers also ups your cred by 2 points.

Comment: Done. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

If you have spare CPU cycles, you can do this with read/awk combination

```
IFS="|"; read  RES CODE < <(echo {"message":"Got an invalid (or empty) URL"}404 | awk -F"}" '{print $1"}|"$2}');
```

Of course, you can set IFS to some invisible character to make it more robust.